# Is there any reason not to switch to BlueHost for ecommerce site?

Tags: web-hosting

If I can manage my own company's website, is there any reason why I shouldn't move it from a local web-host/server to blue host? I'm currently hosted by a full-service web company, but I'd like more flexibility in the changes I make to my site, and I've been learning about web design and I'd like to manage it myself. I made a fake website (using a different domain name)of what the new site would look like were it to be transferred to blue host, and I am confident that I can manage it myself. I just want to know if there are any reasons why it would be unsafe for me to switch over.

Answer (score 1):

> I just want to know if there are any reasons why it would be unsafe
>   for me to switch over.

Well, how confident are you in your sysadmin skills? There is a *lot* more to systems administration than just moving a few sites over. You need to think about things like:

- security patches
- testing new versions of packages before deployment
- configuration management
- netfilter/iptables
- log collection/rotation
- backup/restore procedures
- restore testing
- perfomance monitoring
- etc. etc.

If you are willing to go all-in and truly learn systems administration (not using cpanel/whm/plesk/etc.), then go for it. If that doesn't sound exciting to you, though, then you're better off paying someone else to mind those details for you.

Comment: +1 this question does not provide enough detail to give a specific or definite answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have an account there and as usual I ran a couple security tests myself and I can tell they are faily concerned about security. A few conclusions that I made:

1. The website scripts run with the it's owner account uid, not with some generic `nobody` or `www-data`.
2. The scripts cannot list the folders of other users, nor access the files directly even if you know the name of the files.
3. The scripts can list the `/tmp` folder, but they cannot read the session files of other sites.
4. Attempts to access the `/etc/httpd` folder will terminate your script with a `mod_security` exception.
5. They support contracting an exclusive IP address to your site so you can make it SSL certified.

Note that those conclusions will only apply to the Linux hosting plans, I can't tell how's their Windows managerment.

But if you are still concerned you can always contract the VPS plan and have a dedicated virtual server all for you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's pretty much impossible to comply with PCI-DSS on a shared web hosting provider. Which means you can no longer accept credit cards.